# How to get notified when there is a file created in hdfs directory

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have a hdfs directory where files will be created periodically. I need to get notified when there is a file created in its subdirectory so that I can start reading the file from that hdfs location and send the contents to kafka topic. I found this can be done using HDFS iNotify. But there are few disadvantages like instead of a hdfsdirectory, it notifies when the file is created anywhere in the hdfs. It captures all events happening in the hdfs.

```
public class HdfsINotifyExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, MissingEventsException {

    long lastReadTxid = 0;

    if (args.length > 1) {
        lastReadTxid = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
    }

    System.out.println("lastReadTxid = " + lastReadTxid);

    HdfsAdmin admin = new HdfsAdmin(URI.create(args[0]), new Configuration());

    DFSInotifyEventInputStream eventStream = admin.getInotifyEventStream(lastReadTxid);

    while (true) {
        EventBatch batch = eventStream.take();
        System.out.println("TxId = " + batch.getTxid());

        for (Event event : batch.getEvents()) {
            System.out.println("event type = " + event.getEventType());
            switch (event.getEventType()) {
            case CREATE:
                CreateEvent createEvent = (CreateEvent) event;
                System.out.println("  path = " + createEvent.getPath());
                System.out.println("  owner = " + createEvent.getOwnerName());
                System.out.println("  ctime = " + createEvent.getCtime());
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
          }
       }
      }
     }
```

Instead of monitoring all events type , is there any better way to look only for create file event in a particular hdfs directory.

Comment: You have to look at all events with batch.getEvents())

Answer (score 0):

You can use HSFAdmin API and monitor Event.create (hdfs.inotify.event.type)  along with the HDFS Path to watch (hdfs.inotify.event.path)

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hadoop-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.inotify.GetHDFSEvents/

Comment: The question is using that api, and not using Nifi